# How do i validate strings read from a text file?

Tags: java

i created a function to read from a text file like so

```
public void readClientData() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
        int opt = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (opt == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            // read data from file
            File infile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Reading data from " + infile.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
                String line;

                int id = 1;
                line = rdr.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    processNewClient(id, line);
                    id++;
                    line = rdr.readLine();
                }

                rdr.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Not Found",
                        "Unable to open " + infile.getAbsolutePath(),
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
```

and my text file stores client data in the order of last name, first name, house number and post code like so:

```
Clegg Nick 12 LL1 3AA
```

how may i validate the strings in the text file to ensure that neither *first name* or *last name* may be empty, *house number* must be more than or equal to 1 and *post code* is made up of 2 capital letters, 1 digit, a space, 1 digit and 2 capital letters? Also how do i turn lowercase letters (in the post code) entered into uppercase letters during validation?

Comment: Have you tried anything, any code, to obtain this validation?

Comment: You should try a bit at least. Just a quick search around the web should have already given you the "ToUpperCase()" method.

Take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: If you are using Scanner to retrieve input - correct me if I am wrong, but I think it does not allow an empty input for Strings. The buffer will wait for data and store it into the memory when data has finally been assigned.

Comment: String type has an in build method to put its content into upper case as @Dylan Meeus stated above. However the syntax for that method is ".toUpperCase()" not ".ToUpperCase()";

Comment: i was thinking of using a loop matched with str.length() but my text file would contain several lines of client data and i am not sure how split the lines apart during checking and i do not know how to split all the conditions apart and match them to the areas where they need to be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit too much, you should try it out for yourself first but I can give you some hints:

split the string on whitespaces:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
```

after that you have each value for validation. The rest can be done via normal if().. and some regular expressions.

Try it out and if you get stuck somewhere, you can still ask again but then with some code for us. ;)

P.S.: Since the file content is in a syntax (e.g. name, surname...) you always know the amount of tokens and which token represents a certain value. If ofc the file content could have invalid syntax, you also have to validate this first. (amount of tokens, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Answers for each of the questions:

how may i validate the strings in the text file to ensure that neither first name or last name may be empty. (StringUtils comes from the apache commons libraries. If you don't want to add this, then you need to write a method which says string != null && !"".equals(string.trim()) or something along these lines)

```
StringUtils.isNotBlank(firstName) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(lastName);
```

house number must be more than or equal to 1

```
houseNumber>=1
```

post code is made up of 2 capital letters, 1 digit, a space, 1 digit and 2 capital letters?

- Use regular Expression. use google to find a suitable one.

Also how do i turn lowercase letters (in the post code) entered into uppercase letters during validation?

```
postcode = postcode.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: You should mention that your example needs the `Apache Commons Lang` package as a dependency